# How to delete a random substring in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, substring

I need your help on the given problem

I have a table with column laborder which has given data

**thorax1  [00400 - 00479]
head1  [00100 - 00228]
lab66  [lab661]**

`the whole date is in single column`

we have one page where we can give command to delete any of given string .

for deleting the record we are only giving the code which is in square bracket.

for example if we need to delete  **head1  [00100 - 00228]** we are only giving **00100 - 00228** to delete the string.

here my problem is to write a query where we can give **00100 - 00228** or **00400 - 00479** to delete **head1  [00100 - 00228]** or **thorax1  [00400 - 00479]**
records.

Comment: Given the data:
thorax1 [00400 - 00479] head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]

and the string 00100 - 00228. What is the desired result string?

Comment: if the user is trying to delete 00100 - 00228 .In that case desire output will be thorax1 [00400 - 00479] lab66 [lab661].

Comment: Like wise if the user is trying to delete 00400 - 00479 then the desire output would be head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SQL> with t(col) as (
  2  select 'thorax1 [00400 - 00479] head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]' from dual
  3  )
  4  select regexp_replace(col,'\s{0,1}[[:alnum:]]* \[00100 - 00228\]','') from t
  5  ;

REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'\S{0,1}[[:ALNUM:]]                                          
--------------------------------------                                          
thorax1 [00400 - 00479] lab66 [lab661]                                          

SQL> with t(col) as (
  2  select 'thorax1 [00400 - 00479] head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]' from dual
  3  )
  4  select regexp_replace(col,'\s{0,1}[[:alnum:]]* \[00400 - 00479\]','') from t
  5  /

REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'\S{0,1}[[:ALNUM:]                                           
-------------------------------------                                           
 head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]                                           

SQL> with t(col) as (
  2  select 'thorax1 [00400 - 00479] head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]' from dual
  3  )
  4  select regexp_replace(col,'\s{0,1}[[:alnum:]]* \[lab661\]','') from t
  5  /

REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'\S{0,1}[[:ALNUM:]]*\[LAB6                                   
---------------------------------------------                                   
thorax1 [00400 - 00479] head1 [00100 - 00228]
```

In 10G try this one (move "COL" column name from factoring list to SELECT statement):

```
with t as (
select 'thorax1 [00400 - 00479] head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]' col from dual
)
select regexp_replace(col,'\s{0,1}[[:alnum:]]* \[lab661\]','') from t
/
```

Comment: SQL>     with t(col) as (
   select 'thorax1 [00400 - 00479] head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661]' from dual
  )
   select regexp_replace(col,'\s{0,1}[[:alnum:]]* \[00100 - 00228\]','') from t  ;
    with t(col) as (
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing

Comment: I am getting the above error when I am trying to run this on oracle 10g .Can you please help me to resolve this problem .

Comment: I added the example wich should work in 10G above, please see.

Comment: I think the following might be more logical than `\s{0,1}` at the start of the regex: `(^|\s)`